# Ubuntu: Mounting an encrypted fs dump

Tags: ubuntu, mount, disk-encryption, luks

I have encrypted an Ubuntu partition with the standard partition password encryption ubuntu offers ([LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup), As far as I remember).

I have `dd`-dumped this partition to another computer, and want to mount the `dd` dump file.

Any ideas how mount the encrypted volume dump?

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found an article from [G-Loaded Journal](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/encrypt-devices-using-dm-crypt-and-luks/). In short, we need to make `mount` treat the file as a block device. First, we check which one is free:

```
losetup -f
```

Afterwards, we set it as a block device:

```
losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/container1
```

Other instructions are pretty straightforward.

**Note: make sure you're not using `mkfs` or similar commands on an existing encrypted volume! The instructions might be confusing on that point.**

**Note 2: It is always a good idea to back up a dumpfile before messing with it. Just `cp` your file to someplace else before messing with it!**